# Make a tableview look like native recent calls (combine UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle?)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to make a table view have cells that look [iOS' native call log](http://www.hackphone.co.il/2011/06/images/CallLogEdit1.png). I've got it close just using the storyboard layout editor (Style: Subtitle, Accessory: Detail Disclosure) but I'm not sure how to get that timestamp in there on the right. Is that something I can also layout using the storyboard, or is that something that I'll need to layout programmatically (e.g. subview)?

I think I basically need to combine UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Comment: Have you ever tried to make a custom table cells before ?

Comment: I haven't. The closest I've come to a custom table cell is making one that had a label on the left and a text field on the right, but that was pretty simple (set the style right, then create the textfield and add it as a subview) and I got the code off a question here - so I'm wondering if I should do something similar here. Like use the right-detail view and then add a subview that had a title and subtitle?

Comment: As there no way to combine the cell styles, it seems to be a good idea for timestamps to add  the new label subview on the right side and you already know how to do it. You don't really need to subclass the cell to do it, just be careful reusing the cell to clean the label if there's no value and not to add the second label otherwise. The right labels could be added independently, you don't need (but can use of course) a container subview for that.